# Numba, Jitclass w/ nopython mode and dictionaries

Tags: python, numpy, dictionary, numba

trying to figure out how to skip a class method while using jitclass.

Have a pretty big recursive model (pretty much, a massive for-loop), which - given path-dependent calculations, cannot be vectorized with straight Numpy.

The class runs through a series of numpy arrays, with generally numba-friendly syntax, however I have one section which calls a few of the methods in an ordered fashion:

```
def operations(self, i, ops_order_config):

    ops_dict = self.ops_dict

    for index in range(len(waterfall_config)):
        try:
            if isinstance(ops_config[index], tuple):
                ops_dict[ops_config[index][0]](i, ops_config[index][1])
            else:
                ops_dict[ops_config[index]](i)
        except KeyError:
            pass
```

This part of the model is pretty crucial for flexibility - the "config" is an ordered list of tuples which contain the appropriate method to call, and the respective parameters. The ops_dict holds the actual self. that is called from the config, with proper parameters.

If I'm making a jitclass, is there any way to just skip over jitting this dictionary aspect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, if you make a `jitclass` every attribute has to be typed and dictionaries or lists/tuples containing functions (even if jitted) aren't supported as of numba 0.34. For example trying to use `dict` or `object` as type:

```
import numpy as np
from numba import jitclass

spec = [('dct', dict)]

@jitclass(spec)
class ClsWithObject(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.dct = {}
```

Throws a `TypeError`:

> TypeError: spec values should be Numba type instances, got `<class 'dict'>`

Besides, using `isinstance` as well as `try` and `except` don't work in nopython-mode neither.

Your best option would be to use a `jit`ted function that is called from within a pure Python class.

Comment: Thank you. When jitclass is used and working, is it a safe assumption that nopython mode is being applied?

Comment: @user7038639 Yes. All methods of the class will be compiled in nopython mode. The [docs](http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/user/jitclass.html) mention it explicitly: " All methods of a jitclass is compiled into nopython functions. The data of a jitclass instance is allocated on the heap as a C-compatible structure so that any compiled functions can have direct access to the underlying data, bypassing the interpreter." :)

Comment: Blah, been through those docs 10 times and seemed to have missed that. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

With regards to the use of Dictionaries in Numba compiled functions, as MSeifert said, Numba does not support this.  Within my own work I've run into this problem, and found an implementation (not created by me) of dictionaries in Numba that worked great, it's GitHub repository can be found [here](https://github.com/synapticarbors/khash_numba).

Comment: Numba now has support for dictionaries, and they're crazy fast.